# PHP Slim-3: How to redirect internally to another route

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I have a generic route like below -

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], "/", function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response) use ($app) {
    // Some random version 1 processing here ...
}
```

And I have a v2 version of the same like below -

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], "/api/v2", function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response) use ($app) {
    // Some random version 2 processing here ...
}
```

I have a problem to solve -

*The frontend always hits the v1 of the API (the generic route). I need to internally redirect to v2, based on the parameter `appversion`'s value.*

How can I do this in slim framework routing without issuing 302 redirect headers back to the client? Basically, I need to redirect internally to the server itself.

**Note:** I am aware of Nginx and Apache rewrites. Let us keep them aside and limit the scope to slim framework routing alone.

Comment: What about `$app->redirect('/books', '/library');`?

Comment: This issues a 302 redirect to the client. I want to avoid this to save the unwanted round-trip time.

Comment: Sorry, it would be `$app->redirect('/books', '/library', 301);`.

Comment: `$app->redirect()` responds back to the client with redirect header, either 301 or 302 or any others. If you think of what happens next, the web server responds with 301/302 status along with `location` header, to the client. The client browser then interprets this header information and initiates a new http request with the `location` header's value. **I am trying to avoid going back to client with redirection header, altogether**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is technically possible, but to me, it seems the reason behind your question is that you want to introduce a new version of your API, yet you want not to (or you can not) update the front end to call the new version, and instead, you want to handle this in the back end.

If you are going to decide which version of your API needs to be called based on `appversion` but not the endpoint that was hit, then what is the benefit of defining `v1` and `v2` endpoints?

If someone calls your `v1` endpoint, they want your `v1` response, and if someone needs your `v2` response, they must call your `v2` endpoint. If you return the same response for both `v1` and `v2` endpoints, then you're basically updating your `v1` endpoint behavior.

Anyway, you want to dispatch another route in another route callback, and here is a fully working example showing how it's done using a `subRequest`:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/v1', function($request, $response) use ($app) {
    // Get the appversion query parameter and make the decision based on its value
    $appVersion = $request->getParam('appversion');
    if($appVersion == '1.0') {
        return $app->subRequest($request->getMethod(), '/v2',
            http_build_query($request->getQueryParams()),
            $request->getHeaders(),
            $request->getCookieParams(),
            $request->getBody()->getContents()
        );
    }
    return 'API version: v1, appversion: ' . $appVersion;
});

$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/v2', function($request, $response) {
    return 'API version: v2, request method: ' . $request->getMethod() .', appversion: '. $request->getParam('appversion') . ', body: <pre>' . print_r($request->getParsedBody(), 1);
});

$app->get('/form', function() {
return <<<form
    <form method="POST" action="/v1?appversion=1.0">
        <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
form;
});

$app->run();
```

Now if you try to reach `/v1?appversion=1.0` the response from `/v2` callback will be returned. Trying to reach `/v1` with `appversion` equal to any other value (for example `/v1?appversion=2.0`) causes the app to return the `v1` response.

The `subRequest` method is also capable of handling `POST` requests. Please refer to [method documentation in Slim code repository](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/App.php#L521). The example provides a `/form` URI to demonstrate that.

Comment: To our unfortunate luck, the frontend is an android app which has been released to playstore with a hardcoded endpoint of v1, whereas it is expecting some additional parameters (that v2 provides) to enable a few new features. Anyway, thank you for the response. I have tried to do similar workaround, but failed to forward the POST body in the subRequest() call. Is there a way to do that? The POST body will just be a encoded JSON string.

Comment: That is possible. Please read the [documentation for subRequest() method](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/App.php#L521) and have a look at the updated example in my answer. I added a form to test the `POST` sub request.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed. Wondering how I missed *documentation for subRequest() method*.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it using [optional segments](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#optional-segments) in a single route definition.

```
use Psr\Http\Message\{
    ServerRequestInterface as Request,
    ResponseInterface as Response
};

$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/[{v2:api/v2}]', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    if (isset($args['v2'])) { // You may also check $request->getAttribute('appversion')
        // Version 2 processing here...

        // return $response;
    }

    // Version 1 processing here...

    // return $response;
});
```

Comment: But I need to decide based on a query param rather than URI phrase.

Comment: If you want to decide based on query param you can get the the value of param using `$request->getParam('appversion')` or if you consider to inject values into the request object, you can check `$request->getAttribute('appversion')`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to abstract your invocations and create controllers (i.e. your code won't be so slim).

Example:

```php
function doV2() {
    // ... do V2 things
}
function doV1() {
    // ... do V1 things
}

$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], "/", function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response) use ($app) {
    if($app->request()->params('appversion') === 'v2') return doV2();
    doV1();
}
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], "/api/v2", function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response) use ($app) {
    doV2();
}
```

The reason you cannot 'redirect' internally is because your 'controllers' are anonymous closures so you have no way to name/reference/call them. Instead, if you abstract them out to functions (and yes, you'll probably need to pass in $request/$response too) then you have named methods you can invoke for the appropriate routes.

Instead of defining closures or functions, you could also define your controllers and use SlimPHP's Container Resolution within the router - there's a great example [in the router docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html).

Last up, you *could* get tricky with middleware to change what happens based on your appversion param depending on the complexity of what you're wanting to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for this approach. Definitely the one that works. Will mark this as accepted answer if I couldn't find a better way, within next 24 hours.